# QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have defined this query in a JPA Repository

```
  @org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query("select min(cur.volumeUsd24h), max(cur.volumeUsd24h), "
        + "min(marketCapUsd),       man(marketCapUsd), "
        + "min(availableTickets),   man(availableTickets), "
        + "min(totalTickets),       man(totalTickets)  "
        + "min(maxTickets),             man(maxTickets)  "
        + "from Tickets cur  ")
  Object[] findQueryFiltersValues ();
```

but when I start the app., I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: min near line 1, column 211 [select min(cur.volumeUsd24h), max(
```

I Also tried

```
@Query(value = "select min(cur.volume_usd_24h), max(cur.volume_usd_24h), "
        + "min(market_cap_usd),       max(market_cap_usd), "
        + "min(available_tickets),   max(available_tickets), "
        + "min(total_tickets),       max(total_tickets)  "
        + "min(max_tickets),             max(max_tickets)  "
        + "from tickets cur  ",nativeQuery = true)
```

but I got a compilation error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ",", [ expected
    - Syntax error, insert "]" to complete 
     Expression
```

Comment: Assuming `man` is actually `max`, the original query has a syntax error, which is why the exception. There is no comma after `max(totalTickets)`, which makes the query `max(totalTickets) min(maxTickets)`. See [this sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/53636477) based on the posted code that shows the corrected query in action.

Comment: @manish, please convert to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming man is actually `max`, the original query has a syntax error, which is why the exception. There is **no comma** after `max(totalTickets)`, which makes the query `max(totalTickets) min(maxTickets)`. See [this sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/53636477) based on the posted code that shows the corrected query in action

Answer (score -2):

JPA repository doesn't support min, max functions.

You should change your query to native sql (replace POJO fields to DB column names)

and add nativeQuery = true attribute.

Something like this

```
@Query(value = "select min(cur.volume_usd_24h), max(cur.volume_usd_24h), "
        + "min(market_cap_usd),       max(market_cap_usd), "
        + "min(available_tickets),   max(available_tickets), "
        + "min(total_tickets),       max(total_tickets)  "
        + "min(max_tickets),             max(max_tickets)  "
        + "from tickets cur  ",nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: JPQL [does support](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html) aggregate functions, including `MIN/MAX`.